# React Search by object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, indexof

I am trying to create a search method to search through an array of objects.

Here is what I've got working.

```
searchItemInput = (text) => {
    const search = text;
    const results = Lodash.filter(this.state.itemSearch, (item) => {
        return item.id.indexOf(search) > -1;
    });
    text.length > 0 ? this.setState({ item: results }) : this.setState({ item: [] });
}
```

This is the structure of the data

```
Object {
  "id": "-M86doz_Xnd2nJyJtkNm",
  "image": "image",
  "link": "link",
  "source": "source",
  "title": "title",
}
```

What I am looking for instead is to search by obeject title, so what I've tried is changing `item.id.indexOf(search)` to `item.title.indexOf(search)` but that prompt an error **item.title is undefined**

Comment: There are items with `title` property as undefined

Comment: could you show us an example input and expected output? i have no idea what you want

Comment: Hey adiga, you're right there are some items with undefined `title` , is that an issue? shouldn't I just get the ones that are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was silly :) as pointed out by adiga I was getting the error because some of the items had `title` undefinded.
Removing these elements from the datatbase fixed the issue.
I guess moving on I should check if items have udefined properties and if true than remove them from the filtered array.

**Working method**

```
searchItemInput = (text) => {
    const search = text;
    const results = this.state.itemSearch.filter((item) => {       
       return item.title.indexOf(search) > -1;
    });
    search.length > 0 ? this.setState({ item: results }) : this.setState({ item: [] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find first instance
Use .find()

```
searchItemInput = (text) => {
    const search = text;
    const results = this.state.itemSearch.find(item => item.title === text);
    
    text.length > 0 ? this.setState({ item: results }) : this.setState({ item: [] });
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

To find all

```
searchItemInput = (text) => {
    const search = text;
    const results = this.state.itemSearch.filter(item => item.title === text);

    text.length > 0 ? this.setState({ item: results }) : this.setState({ item: [] });
}
```

Comment: thanks Kyle, but when I try that I get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

```
searchItemInput = (text) => {
    const searchTitle = text;
    const results = this.state.itemSearch.find(item => item.title === searchTitle);
    
    searchTitle.length > 0 ? this.setState({ item: results }) : this.setState({ item: [] });
}
```

You don't need to use the lodash library to do basic calculations like find. You should probably use `searchTitle` instead of `text` to give more context as to what the `string` value was meant to be.

As Kyle mentioned above, `find` will ge you the first occurance and `filter` will get you all of them (you're filtering out the ones that don't match, which in turn gives you all of them.

Comment: thanks Justsolarry, but as with Kyle's solution I get an empty array even ifI use the `searchTitle`